In a post collapse world, how long can cars and other vehicles kept usable?(Not considering fuel)
All the other threads are talking only about fuel and not talking about shelf life of spare parts, I already did enough research on fuels (bio diesel, gasifier, ethanol, human waste , refining old gasoline, etc) and i know how long they can last and how to get better alternatives, the real challenge is spare parts like tire that will be unusable after 5 years even if stored in ideal conditions , i know there is solutions like putting tracks instead of tire or use these fancy airless tires that can be used for 15 years or even more , but what are other parts that has a shelf life (and what is their shelf life) and what can be done to improving their life span?? For example can we use metal made pipes for the pipes and hoses that will be dry and rott after few years?? What are the other parts?
If you asking what type of car I'm asking , i want to know about all kinds of cars so if you have info about any type like diesel, old model , electric ones please give me some data about shelf life of their parts , thanks.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Hello @Amirabasrashvandi, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. The basic problem we're having is that Stack Exchange is not an idea-generating service. It's a solve-a-problem service, and you've not presented us with a problem to solve. Every part on a vehicle has a shelf life depending on how it's been stored. Worse, you're then asking a second question (how can we replace those items?) on a service that allows one and only one question. You see, Stack Exchange is not a free research service, which is why it focuses on one specific problem with the expectation of only one objective best answer.

To better understand Stack Exchange's limitations, please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask]. Thanks.

Batteries (2-6 years)
Although these are going to be the first thing to go, they are also one of the easiest parts of the car to refurbish in a low tech society.  I assume if your survivor can make his own fuel, then descaling and refurbishing a battery should not be too hard. All he needs is epsom salt, baking soda, and sulfuric acid. Epsom salt and baking soda have very long shelf lives and sulfuric acid is relatively easy to to make (Medieval alchemists figured it out over 1000 years).
An average car battery can be refurbished 2-4 times before they become unsalvageable; so, given a some basic know-how, this could be extended to almost 20 years.
Non-fuel fluids (2-10 years)
The biggest problem you've overlooked are your non-fuel fluids: Motor oil, transmission fluid, brake fluid, etc.  All of these fluids not only need to be replaced as part of your routine maintenance, but even in a properly sealed bottle, they only have a shelf life of 2-8 years before they start to risk changes in viscosity and combustibility that could damage your vehicle if used.
The fluids with longer shelf life will depend a lot on the exact model of car, different makes and models require different fluids; so, some cars will run out of usable fluids for one or more systems after 2 years, others after 8. In general, synthetic fluids last longer than natural oil, but every car has a specific set of options in each system, and some of those systems may not have a long lasting option.
So even if you have plenty of old cars in decent shape, by 8 years old, most of your fluids will be way past their expiration date, and those that are just expiring will not be safe to use in your vehicle for very long.  Doing so will risk wrecking your remaining inventory of vehicles pretty quickly; so, you can maybe squeeze out another year or two of using old, bad fluids, but things will start going wrong very quickly.
Manufacturing these fluids is from a chemistry standpoint a notch harder than making your own fuel, but not beyond reason if your main character has a good enough understanding of petrochemistry... but this is far from a normal skill set.
Tires, Timing Belts, and other rubber parts (15-20 years)
In proper storage, they can be still be sold between 5-10 years after manufacturing, but these are generally easier to push past their expiration date than your fluids if you must. Using expired fluids will slowly damage your whole vehicle reducing its total operational lifetime.  Tires and belts in contrast work until they fail which is a bigger liability issue on a busy highway; so, they tend to recommend very conservative change by dates on them. Between 5-10 years is when the manufacturer can no longer guarantee them meaning that they will stop getting as many miles as fresh made tires or belts and some small fraction of them might no longer be safe for normal use, but most of them will still be usable for quite a while.  It is not until about 15 years that you start to see spontaneous failures at a noticably increased rate but some tires and belts will last until 20 years as long as you are not planning to do anything other than occasional, short distance, on-road driving at sub-interstate speeds in mild climate regions.
No matter how knowledgeable your survivor is, modern wheels are grossly impractical to make without access to a tire factory.  Your might be able to make some much lower quality solid rubber or otherwise filled wheels, but the effects on your fuel economy, top safe speed, and how long they last will be very noticable.
Timing belts and most other rubber parts can in theory be replaced with improvised materials.  Scrap cloth, glue, and some wire can make an improvised timing belt, and most rubber seals can be replaced with leather.
Everything Else (20+ years)
Pretty much everything else in a car can be replaced with original parts decades after they've gone out of production as long as you can find them in inventory somewhere.  It will be a big if assuming that you no longer have internet access, but not out of the question.
Also, most of the cosmetic parts of the cars (bumpers, panels, upholstery, etc.) are relatively easy to fabricate, or simply live without since your car technically does not need doors and stuff to drive.

I'd suggest fabrics and upholstery in the 15-20 year range or less depending on the environment. The dashboard isn't that important, but working seats are. (My family has a wonderful story of my father trying to drive a Pontiac Firebird he was buying for my brother to restore while sitting on a milk crate. The story has a moral.... :-)) It's the folds (if stored that way...) that are the biggest problem. Over time on a shelf they create weaknesses in the fabric that tear much more easily. And all of this is assuming the storage location hasn't been compromised. That's a big if.

Ah, one more thing: Some components (shell panels like door panels, frame components) are a lot more rare than others. Body shops obviously have access to these components, but despite decades of involvement in car repair, I wouldn't know where to find them. In other words, there are some components for which the question is much more meaningful than others. Filters for heavy equipment, for example, would be much harder to find than filters for your average sedan. Shelf life is irrelevant when there isn't a shelf to be found.

Thank you sir for all these information i wish i had enough reputation to up vote that , that's what is was asking for, i wanted to know what parts im missing and how long they can last , for all these fluids , is there any DIY things that survivors can do for making a replacement for these fluids? And isn't other parts of the car have shorter shelf lives? Like batteries or seals(i know rubber seals can be replaced by leather made seals )  and can you make it more clear that which fluids last 2 years and which ones last up to 8 years?

@JBH, The cloth on a car seat is easy to mend, replace, or slip cover and not very vital.  The important part is to make sure the frame of the seat is still in good shape.  Most 20-30 year old cars I've seen still have their original seats.  Air filters need frequent replacement when used, but have a very long shelf life.  I'm assuming shelf life limitations on everything because the OP is asking for longest old cars might be kept running, not how long one should expect a specific car to run.

@Amirabasrashvandi I've expanded my answer to hopefully answer these questions better.
